# SQL Server triggers on certain column and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a trigger when there is certain value inserted in certain column instead of whole table, for example I want my trigger to act when the value `NewName` is inserted in the column `Names` on `students` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER newtrg
ON students
AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
  PRINT 'Trigger fired!'
END
```

Comment: You have to remember that values are not inserted. Rows are inserted and one of the columns is NewName. The column is ALWAYS there. Do want this to run on insert and updates? If update what about when the value is updated in the query but the value is the same?

Comment: The first step to making triggers is knowing which DBMS you're using (you have both, MySQL and SQL Server tagged - pick one.)  And the first step to receiving help is *actually asking a question*.  Show your attempts and ask questions about what you're stuck on.

Comment: OK sorry, I mean row instead of value, I edited the post, now can you help me?

Comment: I am using sql server, It's my first post, so I am very grateful for all the advice, thanks.

Comment: How can we help you if you don't ask a question?  What *specifically* are you having trouble with?

Comment: NO. As previously mentioned we don't even know which DBMS you are using. Also, is this only for insert operations? What about updates? If updates, is it only for changes in the value? The basic gist here is that we can help but you have to give us some details. Otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: OK, I am using ms-sql, I edited my post and now you can understand I hope, I want trigger to fire after INSERT

Comment: OK. As coded it will fire after an insert. What is the question?

Comment: It will fire after insert any row in any column, but I want it to fire when there is inserted row "NewName" in the column called "Names"

Comment: Google and learn about the CREATE TRIGGER statement in SQL Server.   Look for details about the virtual table called `inserted` that is available inside a trigger.   An insert trigger fires after every insert, and there is nothing you can do about that.   But you can control what the trigger DOES when it fires based on the contents of the `inserted` table.

Comment: As I said previously, a row will always be inserted. And there will always be a value in the NewName column. It might be NULL but the columns is present in each and every row in the table. Perhaps if you focused on explaining what you want to happen instead of worrying about the value of that column we could help.

Comment: Is it so hard for you to write a code here? I guess, it doesn't take so long, I Googled one thousand times but didn't find exactly what I need, I need one perfect solution and I will understand the rest of it myself.

Comment: Well, i didn't expect it to be so confusing, as I said when I try to insert that row in that column, trigger will prevent from inserting and writes some message, ex. "It cannot be inserted there"

Comment: It isn't hard for me to write code. It is however impossible to provide code that will help you because you seem to not want to share what you want to happen. From the lack of details about the only I would be able to provide is a trigger skeleton which YOU already posted. Maybe if you shared the code you tried it would explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand how triggers work in SQL Server - they fire on a **per statement** level - **not** per row - so you cannot just check to see if the row being inserted contains `NewName` in the `Names` column - an `INSERT` statement could insert dozens of rows at once, and your trigger will only fire **once** for the whole statement.

Therefore, you cannot prevent a single row from being inserted - if your `INSERT` statement inserted 57 rows, and *one of them* contains `NewName` in the `Names` column, you can either just change that value on that particular row, or you can **rollback the transaction** and stop the whole `INSERT` process - **NONE** of the 57 rows will be inserted.

So what do you really want to do, in the end? If your `INSERT` of n rows contains a single row with a value of `NewNames` in the `Names` column - do you want to stop the whole `INSERT` process and rollback the transaction? In that case - use something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER newtrg
ON students
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Inserted WHERE Names = 'NewName')
        -- any of of the rows being inserted contains `NewName` 
        -- in this case, ABORT the whole INSERT
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Or if you want to update those rows after they've been inserted to get a new value (instead of `NewNames`) - try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER newtrg
ON students
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
   UPDATE s
   SET Names = 'SomeOtherValue'
   FROM dbo.Students s
   INNER JOIN Inserted i ON s.StudentID = i.StudentID  -- use the primary key here
   WHERE i.Names = 'NewName'
```

Comment: thanks man, only you understood, the first one was exactly what I needed, thanks for answer as well as for the info you provided, it was really helpful.

Comment: Do you understand that if 100 rows are inserted and _one_ of them contains the value, all 100 rows will be refused?